# pass PHP Array from page to page with POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have an Array $_POST['size']

I want to pass this on to the next page

at first i thought, well thats easy just pass it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size'] ?>"/>
```

obviously this is wrong but is there a way to do it without doing this:

```
foreach ($_POST['size'] as $key => $value){
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="size['.$key.']" value="'.$value.'"/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions - this is a perfect example as to why.

Store $_POST['size'] in $_SESSION['size'] and get it from the session on the page you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could `json_encode` the array (as the value in the hidden element), and then `json_decode` in the next PHP page

Comment: I don't think it matters, `echo '<input type="hidden" name="arrayName" value="'.json_encode($_POST['size']).'"/>';` would be the same result as encoding it first. You could also write to a cookie if you'd like a bit more persistance